# Display in woocommerce order management page custom made <input fields> for shipping methods

Tags: wordpress, input, woocommerce

I have created the following code which I have added to the PHP function to create two input fields placed just below the fixed-rate shipping method on the check out page. In these two input fields customers can enter their shipping provider and account number.

The input fields work perfectly, the problem is that when the order is placed, the values entered (shipping provider name and account number) in these two fields do not appear in the order details on woocommerce.

Can you please advise me how I can make the two fields appear on the woocommerce order management page so that I know what customers have entered?

code:

```
function checkout_shipping_additional_field( $method, $index )
{
    if( $method->get_id() == 'flat_rate:35' ){
        echo '<br>
        <input type="text" id="Name" name="Name" placeholder="Shipping Provider">
        <input type="text" id="Name" name="Name" placeholder="Account Number">';
        
    }
}
```

Comment: The shared code is incomplete to debug the issue and also has mistakes. If you have not written the code to save and validate the fields then those data from extra fields will not save automatically and after saving the data you'll have to write the code to display those details in the needed place. If you can code well in WordPress then you can find many articles on custom fields on checkout and how to display those data with order details.

Comment: Your reply is no helpful. You don't specify where my code is wrong and suggest a possible solution.